# How to include all the jars present at a particular directory in the CLASSPATH in one go?

Tags: java, classpath

I have around hundreds of jars at a particular directory which my application uses. So I thought its hard to add each jars one by one to the classpath. So is there any command or any way so that i can add all the jars at one go. some `*.jar` should add all the jars.

Comment: An example would be to add "...\java_project\jar\*;" to your classpath. The important part is that after the name of the folder, you include the backslash and the star.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you can use a [wildcard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html), as of Java6.   See the section on "Understanding class path wildcards"

> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character `*`, which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. **For example, the class path entry `foo/*` specifies all JAR files in the directory named foo**. A classpath entry consisting simply of `*` expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory.

Prior to Java 6, you had to specify them all individually.

Comment: That's right, as long as you are using "the CLASSPATH environment variable" or "the -classpath (or -cp) command-line option". The pain starts when using a MANIFEST.MF: "However, class path wildcards are not honored in the Class-Path jar-manifest header."

Comment: doesn't work for me, windows 10, also tried "foo/*" and foo/"*"