# wildcard char for Classpath for java 1.5

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a class in java 1.5 in command prompt. I want to include all the jar files from a folder while using javac. when I run the below cmd, the help gets printed on screen. I doubt if wildcard chars are allowed below java 1.6.

Please help.

C:\cfree\52k-br\src\com\checkfree\wps\common\busobj>javac -cp "C:\cfree\52k-br\classes*" IAService.java

Comment: You can't do it prior to Java 6. You will need to specify them individually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include all the jars present at a particular directory in the CLASSPATH in one go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857321/how-to-include-all-the-jars-present-at-a-particular-directory-in-the-classpath-i)

Comment: yes that's what I thought. But is there any easy way of doing it in java 1.5? because to include large number of jar files(say 100 files) will be a tedious thing to do...

Comment: You can use a build automation tool such as Maven or Gradle.

Comment: ok...Thanks for your comments.